# Assigning TABLE typed variables in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-types, table-variable

I've defined a user defined Table type - call it TrackRefsTable

Having declared two variables
DECLARE @FOO1 AS TrackRefsTable
DECLARE @FOO2 AS TrackRefsTable

Is there any way to set one to t'other? The obvious

SET @FOO2 = @FOO1

doesn't work as this assignment method only appears to work for Scalar variables and therefore you get the error
Must declare the scalar variable "@FOO1"

I would hope to be able to avoid having to do INSERT statements to move data from one to the other as this can be an expensive operation.

```
DECLARE @FOO1 AS TrackRefsTable
DECLARE @FOO2 AS TrackRefsTable

-- INSERT INTO @FOO1 here

SET @FOO2 = @FOO1
```

Comment: Table variables don't actually hold references to tables, they *are* tables. You can't dynamically alias or rename them either, so whatever you want to achieve with this has to be accomplished some other way (a flag to use one or the other, for example).

Comment: Yes. I think you're right, Jeroen. I was looking at populating different instances of these and then picking the "right" one to JOIN to something else for actual retrieval. My issue was that with 2 or more of these variables I would have to write 2 or more effectively identical JOINs bloating my SP. But I just realised that I can quite easily create a *second* SP with one of these as a Parameter, so then it's just a question of calling the SP with one or the other, leaving my code nice and lean.

Comment: @JeroenMostert please add your comment as an answer. "What you are trying to do is not possible" is still the correct answer, plus it helped me think of the right solution to get me over this hump so... you deserve the credit, sir!

Comment: I think posting the actual solution would be much more helpful to someone trying something similar in the future, and you have that one. I don't care about credit, so feel free to write up a nice answer and self-accept it.

Comment: cheers - will do when I have it fleshed out

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that the SP in which I implemented this would retrieve relatively unstructured data and then try to apply Sorting and Filtering on it. In order to squeeze maximum performance out of this we had to do things like sometimes populating a Table Variable @FOO1, but then sometimes apply Sorting or Filtering on it with results going into @FOO2 before joining it to an actual Data table to retrieve further column data. If performance wasn't such a big deal, I would have taken the simpler option to simply create a variable @FOOFinal into which all the data would be placed before implementing a single JOIN to get the remaining data. But INSERT INTO @FOOFinal SELECT * FROM @FOO1 (for example) costs precious milliseconds so that wasn't acceptable.

Ultimately, the solution was to simply create a separate SP in which we do the JOIN from such a Table Variable to the other data. Because the Table variable was defined as a Table Variable Type we could (thanks to the fact that we no longer support anything older than SQL Server 2008) use a Table Type as a parameter in the SP. So the solution then is to simply call that SP with either @FOO1 or @FOO2 as the parameter being passed in, and that obviates the need to assign one to the other.